# SQL Server unattended install with dependencies

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, installation

There is an installation system which install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express in unattended mode. All works fine, but on different machines required modules could be missing like Windows installer 4.5, MS XML 6, .NET Framework 2.0 SP2 & 3.5 and more. If one of these components is not found on the target machine then the unattended install just stops without messages and even returning code 0 (no errors) sometimes. What solution can help: to build in all necessary modules into the my installer, or to detect all necessary components and show list of them to user before start installation of SQL Server, or something else?